# Кодировка Android -> MS Excel (Windows)

Tags: java, android, windows, кодировка, excel

Выгружаю [русскоязычные] данные в Excel (формат .xls) из планшета на Android. 
Часть данных прописывается в коде, часть берётся из SQLite.
При открытии получаемого файла: 
в Linux (Libreoffice) - с кодировкой всё нормально;
в Windows 7 (MS Excel) - сплошные кракозябры вида `Р—Р°РєР°Р· в„–`

Онлайн-декодеры с подсказками UTF8 -> CP-1251 и последующие преобразования в коде типа

```
new String(text.getBytes("windows-1251"),"utf-8")
```

так и не помогли (получалось только хуже `пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпї`).

(Также были попытки перевести таким образом из одних имеющихся кодировок в другие и наоборот, но в Винде любая из них всё так же отображается кракозябрами). 
В каком месте я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: А в какой кодировке вы записываете данные в файл?

Comment: Данные в файл xls записывались в стандартной для Android Studio кодировке (вроде, UTF-8 ?), т.е. как есть в коде 
`StringBuilder orderInfo = new StringBuilder();
        orderInfo.append("Заказ ...."); .....`
так потом этот orderInfo и заносится в файл.
Сам файл БД создаётся на чужой стороне. Судя по открытию в тестовом редакторе, там всё же UTF-8 (только в ней нормальные буквы).
Хотя при записи в xls кодировка букв получается одинакова, что напрямую из string, что данные из БД записывать.

Comment: Запись идёт через FileWriter, метод getEncoding говорит "UTF8"

Comment: Такое ощущение, что просто Excel не умеет работать с UTF-8. Как вариант, можно попробовать записать в CP 1251

Comment: Тэк-с... Если открыть xls в самой Винде через Notepad++, то точно такие же кракозябры, как в Excel, получаются, если перекодировать в ANSI или CP-1251. .....

Comment: Глупый вопрос: если открыть созданный файл в Notepad++ сразу после создания (до того как он был открыт в экселе), то в нем тоже кракозябры? если да, то значит проблема где-то в коде, который пишет данные.

Comment: Нет, там нормально открывается.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда записывать их в файл в кодировке CP 1251, тогда эксель должен съесть это нормально. Вообще, странно что он не понимает UTF-8

Comment: Это было, не помогало. Буквы становились только уродливее.

Comment: Может просто вы делали это не правильно? (исходя из примера в вопросе). Для того чтобы записать данные в CP1251, попробуйте в коде, который пишет в файл создать `FieWriter` вот так:   
`new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), Charset.forName("CP1251"))`

Comment: ..... Да.  Неправильно. 
СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ!!! Помогли! =)

Comment: Не за что! :) а какая у вас версия Excel? Все-таки странно что он не может прочитать UTF-8... P.S. Я добавлю свой комментарий как ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(скопировано из моего комментария к вопросу)
Судя по всему, ваша версия Excel не может распознать файл в кодировке UTF-8 (что странно).
Для того чтобы выгрузить данные в файл в CP1251, используйте: `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), Charset.forName("CP1251"))`

Answer (score 0):

Более правильно было сделать, как описано [здесь](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android)

С использованием [библиотеки `org.apache.poi`](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.7):

```
        //New Workbook
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Отдельные ячейки
        Cell c = null;

        //Стилизация ячеек
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //Лист
        Sheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1 = wb.createSheet("myOrder");

        // Строки
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);

        c = row.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue("Item Number");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(1);
        c.setCellValue("Quantity");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue("Price");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));

        // Путь к файлу
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName); 
        FileOutputStream os = null; 

        try { 
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(os);
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
            success = true; 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
        } finally { 
            try { 
                if (null != os) 
                    os.close(); 
            } catch (Exception ex) { 
            } 
        } 
        return success; 
    }
```